# PUT request using cURL PHP returns error 415

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying now to execute PUT request using cURL PHP.

Unfortunately, I receive an error "HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type".
Here is my code :

```
$ch = curl_init();

$proxy = 'api.test.sandbox.mobile.de';
$proxy_port = "8080";

$loginpassw = 'XXX:YYY';

$url='https://services.mobile.de/seller-api/sellers/1086/ads/509939';

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-type: application/json";

$data = array(
    'mileage' => '10000',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $loginpassw);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
echo $data;

curl_close($ch);
```

What is wrong with py request ?

Answer (score 1):

According to their API, you need to send data in either JSON or XML format and specify Content-Type header
https://services.mobile.de/docs/seller-api.html#_media_types

So set the header for writing:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/vnd.de.mobile.api+json');
```

And change POSTFIELDS to

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```

Comment: yes you're right. I've modified $headers with "Content-type:application/vnd.de.mobile.api+json", and I don't have 415 code anymore. Good point.
Now, I get

Comment: Get what? Did you also convert the data to JSON?

Comment: Eveything is OK now, you were right that was a pb of json. Moreover, I couldn't update only one field of the ad, I have to send the complete content of the ad. Thanks a lot for your help.